# Having trouble keeping my CSS arrow on the same line as my header

Tags: html, css, display

I noticed this on both Chrome and Firefox. I have a CSS arrow that I put in my table's header column. However, at small screen widths the arrow goes to the next line despite the `display:inline-block`

How do I keep the arrow on the same line, even at small screen widths?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LgL4jh6j/)

```css
.arrow-up:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="headerRow">
    <th class="headerRow arrow-up">
      Header
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wrap the text and make it also `display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;`  https://jsfiddle.net/rp298zoh/

Comment: When I compress teh sceren to a small width, I see your arrow drifting over to the next line

Comment: Add `white-space: nowrap` to `headerRow` .. https://jsfiddle.net/rp298zoh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the `.headerRow` class.

Comment: oops - just realised the answer was in the comments!